# Blocking contact with RingCentral API

Tags: ringcentral

What is the API we can use to block a contact in RingCentral from calling me?

I have tried successfully to block a contact number in the desktop application and I was successful in it but, out of the API's available, I am not getting any API that can block number from my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Call-Blocking` APIs of RingCentral to block a contact number, update the blocking, allowing a contact, delete a blocked number.

Here is the Call-Blocking APIs:
https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Blocking